# Warning Error: ftp_get(): Transfer complete. in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, ftp

i am trying to download a zip file from server and save it. i get the following error.
the project is in cakePHP

```
Downloading /server/biruhxml20140925.zip ... 
Warning Error: ftp_get(): Transfer complete. in [(pathprefix)/app/Console/Command/Task/ImportUtilityTask.php, line 214]

//server/biruhxml20140925.zip could not be downloaded to (pathprefix)/files/downloaded_files/bild/biruhxml20140925.zip
biruhxml20140925.zip could not be downloaded as the file is not there yet.
```

this is the function which makes the call.

```
public function downloadFTPFile ($remoteFile, $localFile) {
    $connection = $this->ftpConnection;
    ftp_pasv($this->ftpConnection, true);
    $this->out(__('Downloading %s ... ', $remoteFile));
    try {
        if (ftp_get($connection, $localFile, $remoteFile, FTP_BINARY)) {
            $this->out(__('Saved %s', $localFile));
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->out(__('%s could not be downloaded to %s', $remoteFile, $localFile));
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        @unlink($localFile);
        $this->out($e->getMessage());
    }
    $this->nl();
    return false;
}
```

can anyone suggest a work around to get rid of the warning other then setting debug level 0 in core.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered, based on the error message, that the file you try to download is not present on the server?

Your code doesn't do a check if the file is there, I would add that and handle that case accordingly.

Comment: shouldn't ftp_get supposed to return false if file is not present?

Comment: Just because it returns false doesn't mean it can't show a warning. Check if the file exists. If it does the issue is another. But I would do the check in *any* case because I usually want to know the real state (missing file? connection problem? permission issue? ...) instead of just going with "It didn't work, don't care why".